# Is there any free option to replace Google Maps satellite view?

Tags: google-maps, maps

Since next month Google will charge sites using more than 25K maps impressions per day. I'm looking for options to replace Google Maps with some free service.

All I need is satellite imagery of a relatively small area of the U.S., so far I learned about Open Layers but I'm not sure if it's possible to download and host the aerial tiles from some where or if there is some free service with no cap for displaying satellite tiles.

Comment: try asking on http://gis.stackexchange.com/